# How can I override settings in a Nextflow pipeline with a config file

Tags: nextflow

I have a Nextflow nextflow.config file and I have several settings to protect (keys and such). The documentation suggests how to do this, but I can;t find any good examples or a clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In my pipeline, I am writing to MongoDB (CosmosDB) and need to protect the connection string. If the mongodb_connection_string parameter is 'null', the pipeline skips writing to Mongo. This is helpfull for development and testing and setting up a new environment.

I have a config json file in my home directory called **myconfig.json**:

```
    {
       "location": "eastus",    
       "storageAccountName": "asdfgadfsgsaa",
       "mongodbConnectionString":"mongodb://xxx:yyy...."        
    }
```

Inside my nextflow.config, I have

```
params.mongodbConnectionString = 'null'  // bypass writing data to Mongo

profiles {
    local {        
        params {
            sra = 'SRR9686066'  // 180KB
            mongodb_connection_string = params.mongodbConnectionString 
        }
    }
```

The command line to use is:

```
nextflow run $HOME/nf-pass -profile local
```

or

```
nextflow run $HOME/nf-pass -profile local -params-file "$HOME/myconfig.json"
```

When the pipeline starts without a params-file, **mongodb_connection_string** is set to 'null'. When a params-file is used **mongodb_connection_string**  is set to the value of **mongodbConnectionString**  in **myconfig.json**.